# Angular Ionic css not loading

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Again I'm sure this is me over looking something. I am learning angular and i am learning ionic framework all at the same time..

I finally got the calendar working, but its not loading the css. I think its probably something to do with passing the scope properly, but thats why I'm turning here cause i don't know

Calendar.js

```
angular.module('starter.Directives', []);
angular.module('starter.Directives').directive("calendar", function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "templates/calendar.html",
    scope: { selected: "=" },
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.selected = _removeTime(scope.selected || moment());
        scope.month = scope.selected.clone();
        var start = scope.selected.clone();
        start.date(1);
        _removeTime(start.day(0));
        _buildMonth(scope, start, scope.month);
        scope.select = function(day) { scope.selected = day.date; };
        scope.next = function() {
            var next = scope.month.clone();
            _removeTime(next.month(next.month()+1).date(1));
            scope.month.month(scope.month.month()+1);
            _buildMonth(scope, next, scope.month);
        };
        scope.previous = function() {
            var previous = scope.month.clone();
            _removeTime(previous.month(previous.month()-1).date(1));
            scope.month.month(scope.month.month()-1);
            _buildMonth(scope, previous, scope.month);
        };
    }
};
function _removeTime(date){ 
    return date.day(0).hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0); }
function _buildMonth(scope, start, month) {
    scope.weeks = [];
    var done = false, date = start.clone(), monthIndex = date.month(), count = 0;
    while (!done) {
        scope.weeks.push({ days: _buildWeek(date.clone(), month) });
        date.add(1, "w");
        done = count++ > 2 && monthIndex !== date.month();
        monthIndex = date.month();
    }
}
function _buildWeek(date, month) {
    var days = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        days.push({
            name: date.format("dd").substring(0, 1),
            number: date.date(),
            isCurrentMonth: date.month() === month.month(),
            isToday: date.isSame(new Date(), "day"),
            date: date
        });
        date = date.clone();
        date.add(1, "d");
    }
    return days;
}
});
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.day = moment(); 
})
```

my template is including the CSS file properly I've tested with plain html to make sure the css was included.

The original calendar code is written here: http://chrisharrington.github.io/demos/calendar.html

I'm just trying to include it in my ionic project.

Comment: can you try to add the css in the header not in the template ?

Comment: Still doesn't work. If you compare the html from my the original. The original has an extra attribute ng-scope that mine does not but I don't see how that's being generated either

Comment: i don't believe that's linked to the ng-scope. Don't forget to clean the brower cache, i had some surprises with some directives sometimes